# Replace missing symbols from

Tags: fonts, luatex

I'm using Source Sans Pro both as the text and math font. However some symbols are missing in the Latex distribution I'm using (Overleaf 2017 Legacy) which I cannot change due to other complications.

MWE (lualatex, Overleaf 2017 Legacy):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Source Sans Pro}[Ligatures=TeX,SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps,LetterSpace=5}]
\usepackage[math-style=upright]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Source Sans Pro}

\begin{document}

$A^*$

\end{document}
```

[image]

How can automatically replace any missing font using a similar font?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Source Sans is not a math font.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion of a math font to pair with Source Sans?

Comment: What about Noto Sans Math?

Comment: The best solution I found was to use source sans for letters and numbers and fira sans for the symbols:

`\usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{FiraMath-Regular}[Path=fonts/, Extension = .otf]
\setmathfont{Source Sans Pro}[
    range={up/{greek,Greek,latin,Latin,num}, 
    it/{greek,Greek,latin,Latin,num}, 
    bfup/{greek,Greek,latin,Latin,num}, 
    bfit/{greek,Greek,latin,Latin,num},
    frak/{greek,Greek,latin,Latin,num}},
    ]`